# An empty array of likes even though correct permissions - Facebook App

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm going slightly mad because of my problem. I prepared facebook app based on facebook-php-sdk. My app's permisions are:

```
publish_acions, user_location, user_likes, friends_likes
```

Everything goes correct with that code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '####',
  'secret' => '####',
));
```

I can also receive

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
$userId = $user_profile['id'];
```

But I can't receive

```
$user_likes = $facebook->api('/me/likes/');
```

It just gives me an empty array (I'm quite sure I like the page). So what's the reason?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: are you trying with an app developer or admin or a random user? and are you sure you authorized the user for user_likes?

Comment: Admin. I'm not sure about the authorisation - I thought It's the api's thing and the permissions settings.

Comment: in that case, you most likely did not authorize the permission correctly. also, friend permissions are deprecated and don´t work anymore, and it´s publish_actions, not publish_acions ;)

Comment: Jup, publish_actions, sure thing. Could You give me some suggestions about the authorization way? I was totally sure that it's all about api and permissions's settings :(

Comment: never user the php sdk for login. FB.login is much better and easier to handle and debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Use The JavaScript for the login process, it´s much easier to handle and debug. Also, it´s better for the usability, because it does not redirect: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.1

Use the "scope" parameter as it is mentioned in the docs and check if the required permissions are really asked for in the authorization popups.

Btw, the correct endpoint would be /me/likes (without the slash at the end), just another idea why it does not work.

And then there is the review process, most permissions (like user_likes) need to get approved by Facebook before they can be used for other users (except for users with a role in the App settings). Check out the changelog and the review guidelines for more information:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login

Friend permissions are deprecated btw, there is no "friends_likes" anymore.

Comment: That's totally what I wanted! Thank You Man!